# Multi tenant OpenID integration to ASP.Net MVC web application without native .Net authentication support

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, appsource

We have a Asp.Net MVC web application with custom authentication functionality (not using .Net authentication framework). Now we want to integrate it with Azure Active Directory with multi tenant support. I have followed following application example and the sample app directs me to AD login page.

However, when I do same thing in my app, it just redirects me to http://localhost:14223/app/login.aspx?
We are not using FormsAuthentication or anything, so I am not sure how this is happening and what is the process to avoid it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please provide more details such as - is your authentication set as Anonymous? Did you install OWIN packages and created an startup file? I would recommend you to take a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-aspnetwebapp) for a step-by-step instructions -- it is for v2 endpoint, so if you already have an app registered in Azure Portal, I'd recommend you changing the endpoint to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0} instead of v2.0 and skip the app registration.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this part](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquring-a-token-return-AuthenticationResult-and-possibly-UserInfo#confidential-client-applications-will-rather) of ADAL.NET's conceptual documentation for the ways for confidential client applications (Web applications, Web APIs, daemon applications) to acquire tokens.

More generally you might want to read the full page: [Acquiring a token: this depends on the kind of application](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquring-a-token-return-AuthenticationResult-and-possibly-UserInfo#confidential-client-applications-will-rather)